# Win10 Media Creation with Volume Licenses?

Tags: windows, installation

TLDR:

I have working Win10 licneses. (this is NOT a licensing question). Creating install media from these ISOs with the Win7 DVD to USB tool. Only the Win10 Media Creatino tool works, but that doesn't have enterprise on it.

How do I use the media creation tool with the downloaded Enterprise ISO sources?

Background:
I have Win10 Enterprise licenses in the volume license service center. I downloaded the ISOs, and used the [old Windows 7 USB creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/windows-usb-dvd-download-tool), but newer tablets do not see this installation or boot from it. The newer tablets see Win10 bootable USB sticks that are made from the [Windows 10 Media Creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10#34de222e-6944-44aa-8f45-8e96988880a4) without any issues.

The problem is: when I [setup the ei.cfg and pid.txt files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-setup-edition-configuration-and-product-id-files--eicfg-and-pidtxt) with the keys for Window 10 Pro or Enterprise from our VLSC account, it tells me "The product key entered does not match any of the Windows images available for installation. Enter a different product key" which is in the troubleshooting section for that article I just referenced.

So, my question is:
How do I create a bootable USB for Win10 from the downloaded ISOs from VLSC *in the same manner* that the Media Creation Tool makes them so newer PCs will boot from it?

Note: The tablet in question has Windows 10 Home licenses embedded in the UEFI BIOS, so in order to not use those, I need to have ei.cfg and pid.txt working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took a lot of digging, but it turns out the Media Creation Tool (MCT) has command line switches that allow me to specify Enterprise.

Here's the correct, working answer:

`MediaCreationTool1803.exe /Eula Accept /Retail /MediaArch x64 /MediaEdition Enterprise`

MCT will then prompt you for your key, and viola! It works.

This does NOT work with Enterprise LTSB. Probably needs a different `/MediaEdition` argument, but there are no good docs on this, so I could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

The closest way to achieve it would be with a manual preparation of the USB stick, installing windows and activating it post installation:

In a Windows machine, open CMD as an administrator and perform these commands/steps:

> 1. diskpart
> 2. list disk
> 3. select disk 1 (or maybe disk 2, disk 3, etc. Please check that your selected disk is the right one, because diskpart will list your
>      hard drive, your ssd, everything. And all changes cannot be undone. I
>      am not responsible for any data loss.)
> 4. clean
> 5. create partition primary
> 6. active (to make the partition active and bootable)
> 7. assign
> 8. format fs=exfat quick

Finally, just open the .ISO file, copy all contents to the USB stick and restart your machine. If you changed your BIOS or UEFI to be able to boot from USB, then the stick is fully ready to install Windows from it.

Comment: Nope. UEFI still doesn't see it. Also, I fail to see how this would be superior / different to using the Win7 DVD USB tool mentioned above.